# Paypal recurring payment

Tags: paypal

I've got an enhancement from client and big trouble with answer if it is possible or not to do.

What I have is a web which provides seo service.
Client types phrase than chooses service option etc.
There are severals service options like:

- single payment - service will be active per only 90 days
- membership - client declare to pay a sum of money every 90days (recurring payment)
- membership + extra support - same as membership but + extra sum of money

1) Suppose that client choosed first option and after 90 days decided to continue service.
Is it possible to set reccuring payment via paypal without need of client's interference* (we do not store any credit cards numbers in database).

2) Suppose that client choosed second option and after about 10 days decided to get extra support. 
    Is it possible to change sum of money which we are charging from client every 90 days, without his interference*.

```
* client don't have to fill up payment form (paypal side) once again.
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me with this issue. If it is possible which paypal accout do I  have to get.
Thanks
Maciek

---

Thanks for reply. However I still don't get it. 
Do you know how can I (as merchant) from my website/shop admin panel (not paypal profile site) cancel subscriber's subscription ?

In PDF "Recurring Payments API Overview" I have read that 
"N O T E : There is currently no API access to allow merchants to modify or cancel a profile." 
and in limitation: 
"You cannot modify or cancel a recurring payment profile using the Recurring Payments API".

What can I do with this issue? Maybe there is another Paypal API that lets me to do what I want.

By the way reading PayPal Payments Standard Integration Guide I found that without subscriber's log in it is not possible to upgrade his account. Is it possible to upgrade ( charge more money monthly) without his log in?

Thanks
Maciek

Comment: For anyone having problems with recurring payments you can check this great article http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-integrate-your-website-with-paypal-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PayPal has a "subscription" mode to handle this sort of thing, including the ability to modify a subscription.  See https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring.